# custom Prelude module -- bad idea?

Tags: haskell

I just realized that I can define my own Prelude module and carefully control its exports.
Is this considered bad practice?

Advantages:

- No need to repeatedly import a "Common" module in large projects.
- No need to write "import Prelude hiding (catch)".

Comment: One obvious disadvantage is readability. People *expect* that the Prelude functions are, well, the Prelude functions, unless explicitly hidden. If there's no `hiding (map)`, it sounds very uncomfortable to encounter a `map` that isn't the ordinary one.

Comment: I use `basic-prelude` on some of my projects.  I think a custom per-project prelude might be going too far, but if something can become popular, I would support that.

Comment: @singpolyma Thanks for the `basic-prelude` notion!

Answer (score 9):

In general its a bad idea, as you end up with code written in your own idioms that isn't going to be easy to maintain by others.

To communicate with others you need a shared language of symbols. The `Prelude` is our core language, so if you redefine it, expect confusion.

The exception to this rule would be when developing an embedded domain-specific language. There, making a custom Prelude is entirely a good idea, and is indeed why it is possible to redefine the Prelude (and inbuilt syntax) in the first place.

By all means have your own additional modules, but don't override the Prelude.